# Drag functionality in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add drag functionality to my application. if the user drags on particular columns of a row then a jquery dropdown has to be called with that specific ng-models values as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The best library would be to use [mobile-angular-ui](http://mobileangularui.com/) library. If you want to include the gestures only, just have to include there gestures.js which is very lightweight.